# Boolean value not updating on Heroku, but works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My application consists of `Items`. They have a `status` attribute that's a boolean. I added it to items by doing `rails g migration AddStatusToItems status:boolean`. To show the status of an item as either complete or pending, in the view, I just do

```
<% if status? %>
Complete
<% else %>
Pending
<% end %>
```

Oh yeah, I also added `:status` to the params hash in the controller.

It works as it should locally, but on Heroku the status just goes back to pending. Here's the log on Heroku. How can I get this working? [image]

```
 class ItemsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :upvote]

      # GET /items
      # GET /items.json
      def index
        @items = Item.all.order('created_at DESC')
      end

      # GET /items/1
      # GET /items/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /items/new
      def new
        @item = Item.new
      end

      # GET /items/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /items
      # POST /items.json
      def create
        @item = current_user.items.new(item_params)


        respond_to do |format|
          if @item.save
            format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @item }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /items/1
      # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @item.update(item_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /items/1
      # DELETE /items/1.json
      def destroy
        @item.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to items_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_item
          @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def item_params
          params.require(:item).permit(:name, :quantity, :boughtfor, :soldfor, :user_id, :status)
        end
    end
```

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the value of status in the database.

Comment: Look at the server output. It says "status" => "1". Doesn't that mean that I am changing it in the database? I mean... It works just fine locally.

Comment: That just means that it is being passed in the params hash, not that it is being updated. Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` after creating the status field?

Comment: Can you show your ItemsController?

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: somtimes u need to restart your server after migration...try running "heroku restart"